# error in forms.py wile runserver or migrate

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to add one more field of profile picture in my registration form but after saving the code and while trying to run locally it shows error inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation . please help if you can see error
[my forms.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhJfM.png)

[error while runserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lPRy.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste your code into your question rather than attaching a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, the issue is that you have  inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. You should decide whether you're going to use spaces or tabs, then go through your project and fix the occurrences. Most IDE's have a tool that can do that for you. It looks like you're using Atom. Here's a [tutorial](https://simpletechtutorials.blogspot.com/2016/12/atom-how-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces.html) that shows you how to convert from tabs to spaces.